# How to bind .Url(Url.Action()) property to toolbar in kendo ui grid(html)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, url.action

i have a grid developed using kendo ui and asp.net mvc4 razor.in there i have used the html syntax for kendo grid instead of asp.net mvc.

this is the code of my grid

```
    <div id="example" class="k-content">
    <div id="batchgrid">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    $("#batchGrid").click(function () {
        var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://demos.kendoui.com/service",
                        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            batch: true,
                            pageSize: 20,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    id: "ProductID",
                                    fields: {
                                        ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        ProductName: { validation: { required: true} },
                                        UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                        UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true} },
                                        Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                        TotalStock: { type: "number" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            //                            group: {
                            //                                field: "UnitPrice", aggregates: [
                            //                                        { field: "UnitPrice", aggregate: "sum" },
                            //                                        { field: "TotalStock", aggregate: "sum" }
                            //                                     ]
                            //                            },
                            aggregate: [{ field: "TotalStock", aggregate: "sum"}]

                        });

        $("#batchgrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            dataBound: onDataBound,

            navigatable: true,

            filterable: {
                messages: {
                    and: "And",
                    or: "Or",
                    filter: "Apply filter",
                    clear: "Clear filter",
                    info: "Filter by"
                },
                extra: false, //do not show extra filters
                operators: { // redefine the string operators
                    string: {
                        contains: "Contains",
                        doesnotcontain: "Doesn't contain",
                        startswith: "Starts With",
                        endswith: "Ends"
                    },
                    number: {
                        eq: "Is Equal To",
                        neq: "Not equal to",
                        gte: "Greater than or equal to",
                        lte: "Less than or equal to",
                        gt: "Greater than",
                        lt: "Less than"
                    }
                }
            },

            reorderable: true, //not working

            selectable: "multiple",

            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100]
            },

            height: 430,
            width: 300,

            toolbar: [
                    {
                        name: "my-create",
                        text: "Add new record"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "save",
                        text: "save changes"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "cancel",
                        text: "cancel changes"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "export",
                        text: "Export To Excel"
                    }
            ],

            columns: [
            //                            { field: "ProductID", title: "No", width: "90px" },
                            {title: "No", template: "#= ++record #", width: 45 },
                            { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name", width: "350px" },
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "150px" },
                            { field: "Discontinued", title: "Purchase", width: "110px" },
                            { field: "TotalStock", title: "Total Stock", width: "150px", footerTemplate: "Total : #= kendo.toString(sum, 'C') #", format: "{0:c2}" }
            //{ command: ["destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "175px" }
            ],


            export: {
                cssClass: "k-grid-export-image",
                title: "people",
                createUrl: "/Home/ExportToExcel",
                downloadUrl: "/Home/GetExcelFile"
            },

            groupable: {
                messages: {
                    empty: "Drop columns here"
                }
            }, //not working

            columnMenu: {
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                messages: {
                    columns: "Hide/Show Columns",
                    filter: "Apply filter",
                    sortAscending: "Sort (asc)",
                    sortDescending: "Sort (desc)"
                }
            },

            resizable: true,

            dataBinding: function () {
                record = (this.dataSource.page() - 1) * this.dataSource.pageSize();
            },

            sortable: {
                mode: "multiple"
            },
            sort: { field: "ProductID", dir: "asc" },

            editable: { mode: "incell", createAt: "bottom" }
        });

        //custom global variables
        newRowAdded = false;
        checkedOnce = false;

        var grid = $("#batchgrid").data("kendoGrid");
        $(".k-grid-my-create", grid.element).on("click", function (e) {

            window.newRowAdded = true;

            var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
            var total = dataSource.data().length;
            dataSource.insert(total, {});
            dataSource.page(dataSource.totalPages());
            grid.editRow(grid.tbody.children().last());
        });

        grid.bind("saveChanges", function () {
            window.newRowAdded = false;
            //                        var grid = $("#batchgrid").data("kendoGrid");
            //                        grid.dataSource.sort({ field: "ProductID", dir: "asc" });
            //            GetValOf();

            //            var grid = $('#batchgrid').data("kendoGrid");
            //            var total = 0;
            //            $.each(grid.dataSource.view(), function () {
            //                total += this.TotalStock;
            //            });
            //            alert(total);
        });

        grid.bind("cancelChanges", function () {
            window.newRowAdded = false;
        });

        $(".k-grid-export", "#batchgrid").bind("click", function (ev) {
            // your code
            //            alert("Hello");
            var grid = $("#batchgrid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.dataSource.pageSize(parseInt($("#batchgrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().length));
            excelImport();
        });
    });
</script>
```

but i got some example code for importing grid data to excel and in there they used asp.net mvc syntax.

here is the code.

```
@(
 Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("Grid")
                .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
                                .Model(m =>
                                {
                                    m.Id(p=>p.ProductID);                              
                                })
                        .Read(r => r.Action("Read", "Home"))
                )
                .ToolBar(toolBar => 
                    toolBar.Custom()
                        .Text("Export To Excel")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "export" })
                        .Url(Url.Action("Export", "Home", new { page = 1, pageSize = "~", filter = "~", sort = "~" }))
                )
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice).Format("{0:c}");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.QuantityPerUnit);
                })
                .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("onDataBound"))
                .Pageable()
                .Sortable()
                .Filterable()
)
```

but my problem is i need to add below line of code to my grid(in first code mentioned above).

```
.ToolBar(toolBar => 
                        toolBar.Custom()
                            .Text("Export To Excel")
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "export" })
                            .Url(Url.Action("Export", "Home", new { page = 1, pageSize = "~", filter = "~", sort = "~" }))
                    )
```

but im stucked with this single line

```
.Url(Url.Action("Export", "Home", new { page = 1, pageSize = "~", filter = "~", sort = "~" }))
```

can somebody please tell me that how to use this code in my html grid..

Comment: Why you used attribute after new? remove that so its works.

Comment: i need to pass some values to the controller that's why i used attributes after new.. further more here is the code of my controller class.. if you can please tell me that how can i pass those values to the controller..

Comment: 'public FileResult Export([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {}'

Comment: Call JS function and execute controller method with passing some parameter.

Comment: i need to pass parameters like the way i mentioned in my code and then the DataSourceRequest object will handle those request.. is there any possible way to achieve that? kindly please concern about this too.. please..

Answer (score 0):

Write Toolbar manual

```
<div class="k-toolbar k-grid-toolbar k-grid-top">
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext " id="exportCsv" href="/Home/ExportToCsv?take=50&amp;skip=0&amp;page=1&amp;pageSize=10&amp;filter=~&amp;sort=" id="exportToCSV"><span></span>Export CSV</a>
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext " id="exportXls" href="/Home/ExportToXls?take=50&amp;skip=0&amp;pageSize=10&amp;filter=~&amp;sort=" id="exportToExcel"><span></span>Export Excel</a>  
</div>
```

then add databound to kendoGrid

```
....
            editable: false, // enable editing          
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            scrollable: false,
            dataBound: onDataBound,
            columns: [.....
```

then write 'onDataBound' function

```
<script>

    function onDataBound(e) {
        var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');

        var take = grid.dataSource.take();
        var skip = grid.dataSource.skip();
        var page = grid.dataSource.page();
        var sort = grid.dataSource.sort();
        var pageSize = grid.dataSource.pageSize();
        var filter = JSON.stringify(grid.dataSource.filter());        

        // Get the export link as jQuery object
        var $exportLink = $('#exportXls');

        // Get its 'href' attribute - the URL where it would navigate to
        var href = $exportLink.attr('href');

        // Update the 'take' parameter with the grid's current page
        href = href.replace(/take=([^&]*)/, 'take=' + take || '~');

        // Update the 'skip' parameter with the grid's current page
        href = href.replace(/skip=([^&]*)/, 'skip=' + skip || '~');

        // Update the 'page' parameter with the grid's current page
        href = href.replace(/page=([^&]*)/, 'page=' + page || '~');

        // Update the 'sort' parameter with the grid's current sort descriptor
        href = href.replace(/sort=([^&]*)/, 'sort=' + sort || '~');

        // Update the 'pageSize' parameter with the grid's current pageSize
        href = href.replace(/pageSize=([^&]*)/, 'pageSize=' + pageSize);

        //update filter descriptor with the filters applied

        href = href.replace(/filter=([^&]*)/, 'filter=' + (filter || '~'));

        // Update the 'href' attribute
        $exportLink.attr('href', href);

        $('#exportCsv').attr('href', href.replace('ExportToXls', 'ExportToCsv'));
    }
</script>
```

And this is the Action, and parameters

```
      public FileResult ExportToXls(int take, int skip, IEnumerable<Sort> sort, string filter)
        {
            try
            {
                Filter objfilter = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Filter>(filter);

                var lstContactFormData = XmlData.GetIletisimBilgileri().OrderByDescending(i => i.tarih);

                //Get the data representing the current grid state - page, sort and filter
                //IEnumerable products = _db.Products.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;
                IEnumerable contactsDatas = lstContactFormData.AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(take, skip, sort, objfilter).Data;

...
...
```